# integral involves positive definite function and Bessel function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, bessel-functions, positive-definite

Could the following integral be $0$?
 \begin{eqnarray*}
  \lim_{x \to 0^+}   \int_0^\pi  \vartheta^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}} \frac{J_{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}  ( x \vartheta )}{x^{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}}  g(\vartheta) d \vartheta
   \end{eqnarray*}
where $g(\vartheta)$ is a continuous function on $[0,\pi]$, $J_\alpha (x)$ is the Bessel function, and
$$\int_0^\pi  \vartheta^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}} J_{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}  ( x \vartheta )  g(\vartheta) d \vartheta >0$$
for $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

With your assumption, and with asymptotic behavior as $ x\rightarrow 0$:
$$J_a(x)\sim \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(a+1)}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^a$$
then
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \lim_{x \to 0^+}   \int_0^\pi  \vartheta^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}} \frac{J_{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}  ( x \vartheta )}{x^{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}}  g(\vartheta) d \vartheta
=
 \frac{1}{2^{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})}\int_0^\pi  \vartheta^{2\alpha}  g(\vartheta) d \vartheta
   \end{eqnarray*}
which depends on the last inteegral.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Actually, I get your equation. What I want to prove is the left side of your equation is always positive. So I was wondering if there exist another way to discuss this limit?